# some characters display as "??????" in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
I've problem on adding post to my wordpress site. When i add this "**Let't try Thai         
website Sbobet ทงบอลออนไลน์**" to my site, it shows "**Let't try Thai website Sbobet ????????**" .
```

I've tried meta charset="UTF-8" in index file. But the problem is still there.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to add the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="th">
```

all the best
Fab.